# Rails simple form undefined local variable or method `resource' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got 2 steps survey, 1 step submits new record of `SurveyResults` and redirect_to the second step which updates `User` model based on the answer selected by the user (radio buttons). To handle second step I created new `controllers/users/UserExperienceLevelsController` with below update method:

```
def update
  if current_user.update(experience_level: users_user_experience_level_params)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User experience level was successfully submitted.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def users_user_experience_level_params
  params.fetch(:users_user_experience_level).permit(:experience_level)
end
```

With views:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: edit_users_user_experience_level_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <%= f.input :experience_level, collection: User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
NameError in Users::UserExperienceLevels#edit
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000bbd0>
```

[EDIT]

routes:

```
  namespace :users do
    resources :user_experience_levels, only: [:edit, :update]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two local variables in your view that presumably should be sent from the controller. Local variables can be passed to the view through the `locals` option:

```
render :edit, 
       locals: { resource: current_user, resource_name: :user }
```

Its not well documented but you can pass local variables when rendering views and not just partials. This technique lets you bypass using controller instance variables to pass data to the view.

Another option is to declare helper methods from your controller:

```
module Users
  class UserExperienceLevelsController 

    # ...

    def resource
      current_user
    end

    helper_method :resource

    def resource_name
      :users_user_experience_level
    end
  
    helper_method :resource_name
  end
end
```

This exposes these methods to the view. This is useful if you want to use inheritance or some other form of composition to to setup the data.

Comment: I added `locals` option inside of else if block (`if .... else render :edit, locals: { resource: current_user, resource_name: :user }`) and I'm getting the same error. Shouldn't I pass a local option to the `simple_form_for` somehow?

Comment: According to the error message the request is handled by `Users::UserExperienceLevels#edit` and not `#update`. Using the approch with helper methods would let you provide the data without explicitly passing locals to each render call.

Comment: I'm totally confused, so should I create an edit action and pass them `current_user`. If I do that nothing really change, stil the same error.

Comment: Ok I've just copy/paste second approach with `resource` and `resource_name` methods (this is the first time I've seen something like this) and now the page shows up but when I push submit button I'm getting an error: `param is missing or the value is empty: users_user_experience_level`

Comment: Its hard to really say without the logs showing the request but what I'm guessing is happening here is that rails is implicitly rendering. If you have a view that corresponds to an action but no action in your controller rails will just pretend that the method exists and render the view. Its part of the convention over configuration magic that can be somewhat suprising. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ImplicitRender.html

Comment: If I remember correctly the `as:` option for `simple_form_for` sets the nesting for the param keys. So if you do `simple_form_for foo, as: :bar` the params end up in `params[:bar]`. Just adjust the return value of resource_name to what you want in the recieving end when you whitelist the params.

Comment: The whole method is kind of strange though and I would just do `User.update(params.require(:user).permit(:experience_level))` if you want to update just that user attribute.

Comment: Finally it works! Now I need to figured out how to block editing of this record if it's already exists without using the Pundit gem I guess. Switchover from GrapeAPI app to the standard Rails monolith is truly a nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

`render :edit` just render template, the `controller action :edit` will not be called, so you need to provide the resource variable.

If you want render directly form view then you can do:

```rb
def update
 if ...
 else
   render partial: 'form', locals: {resource: Resource.find(step1_submit_resource_id)}
 end 
end
```

If you want render edit view

```rb
def update
  if ...
    # ...
  else
    @resource = Resource.find(step1_submit_resource_id)
    render :edit
  end
end
# edit view
...
<%= render 'form', resource: @resource %>
...
# _form view
<%= simple_form_for(resource, ...
```